# Coroutine Lifecycle Scope and isActive not working?

Tags: java, android, kotlin-coroutines

I've been working with Coroutines thinking they work like Java Threads where the isAlive boolean is the same as checking for isInterrupted() in a long running operation such as writing a large file.

In the past the Coroutine has worked as expected but in the current version 1.6.1-native-mt it doesn't seem to work like that any more. In the code below, the code inside the isAlive check doesn't seem to run even when I switch to the 1.6.1 non-multithreaded library.

If this is the way it's supposed to work? What should the correct way of performing a clean-up after a job is cancelled?

Also when attaching a Coroutine to a scope, in this case the Activity, shouldn't it be auto-cancelled when a new Activity is started? It seems to keep running if it isn't cancelled manually like in Java during the onPause()/onStop() phase.

Kotlin Coroutine:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val tag = "TEST"
    lateinit var job: Job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.stopbutton)

        job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            (1..120).forEach {

                // big long operation e.g. writing a large data file
                Log.d(tag, "ticking $it")

                if ( !isActive ) {
                    // this code never happens after....
                    // 1. button is clicked to cancel job
                    // 2. app is killed
                    Log.d(tag, "ticking stopped by button")
                    // clean up the partially written file
                    return@launch
                }

                delay(1000)
            }

        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            job.cancel()
        }

    }

}
```

Expected Output (Should be same as Java Thread code):

```
ticking 1
ticking 2
ticking 3
ticking stopped
```

Actual Coroutine Output:

```
ticking 1
ticking 2
ticking 3
```

And the Java code for handling thread interrupts.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected Thread t = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for ( int x = 0; x < 120; x++ ) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "ticking " + x);

                    if ( interrupted() ) {
                        Log.d("TEST", "ticking stopped by button");
                        return;
                    }

                    // just for demoing
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);

                }

            }
        };
        t.start();

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                t.interrupt();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

After following @Sergio and @Pawel's quick replies I have removed delay() and replaced it with SystemClock.sleep() just like in Java to simulate long operations. Now it works as expected although I wonder why so many tutorials use it without highlighting the issue.

Still trying to figure out what is the point of attaching a coroutine to a lifecycle scope if it doesn't auto cancel() onstop() such as described here:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629

Or maybe I'm missing the point?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `delay()` function internally also checks for cancellations, and if the cancellation happens during its execution it stops a coroutine by throwing a cancellation exception. To get the result you want try to use `Thread.sleep()` or similar blocking sleeping methods instead of `delay` or try to wrap calling `delay()` into `try-catch` block.

Comment: Ah, I see. After taking the delay() call out it's working as expected now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation in coroutines is indeed [cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) and checking `isActive` is one way to do it properly.

But you've missed the part that built in suspending functions (in this case `delay`) check and throw a `CancellationException` internally so you won't get another loop execution after cancellation.

If you want to react to cancellation you can set a [`CompletionHandler`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html):

```
job.invokeOnCompletion {
    when(it?.message) {
        null -> Log.d("Completed normally")
        "ButtonPressed" -> Log.d("Cancelled by button press")
        else -> Log.d("Cancelled: ${it.message}")
    }
}
```

And alter your cancellation code so you can discern the cancellation message:

```
job.cancel("ButtonPressed")
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about invokeOnCompletion() =)

Answer (score 0):

If the coroutine is cancelled, then `delay()` or practically any other suspend call may throw `CancellationException`. So one approach is to simply use try-catch-finally to clean up on exit, as those are still run.

If you need to call suspend functions during cleanup, you need to use `withContext(NonCancellable) { ... }` so that the suspend functions inside that don't immediately throw `CancellationException` again.

```kotlin
  try {
     (1..120).forEach {
        // big long operation e.g. writing a large data file
        Log.d(tag, "ticking $it")
        delay(1000)
     }
  } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
    withContext(NonCancellable) {
       Log.d(tag, "ticking cancelled")
       // clean up interrupted file generation
    }
    throw ex
  }
```